# How to do incremental Jenkins Maven builds on large Multi-Module Project

Tags: maven, jenkins, incremental-build

I have a large multi-module project which takes about an hour to build from clean in Jenkins.

I am using Maven CI-friendly versioning using ${revision} for all module versions in the multi-module project, and I'm passing in something like -Drevision=${BUILD_NUMBER} from Jenkins.

This works fine, but it is so inefficient when deployed across a team of 20-ish, with a new build for every Pull Request. Who wants to wait an hour every time a single line of code changes?!?

**How can I get incremental build working with my project structure?**

The obvious problem with the 'incremental build' tickbox is that when I build the changed modules (e.g. version 5) they will all depend on unchanged modules also with version 5, yet the last version that was actually built may be 1,2,3 or 4.

So ${revision} across the whole multi-module project will break incremental building

My other issue is that I am using multiple slaves, meaning I cannot simply rely on the file system being unchanged since last build (same Maven Local Repo, same working tree, etc).

In order to share unchanged artifacts between builds on different slaves I'd have to either use the Maven Repo (e.g. Nexus), or have some kind of file copy over SSH (e.g. each build transfers back up to Master and then down to slaves)

Comment: How many modules do you have? How many tests do you have? How long does the build take? How long do the tests take? Furthermore do you use `-T 4` or similar?  If you have a incremental checkbox in your jenkins you are using an extreme old version of Jenkins...

Comment: About 400 modules, 2000 tests. Parallel builds don't work because we have a load of horrible C/C++/JNI/Swig-wrapper projects built with combinations of ant/make wrapped in maven poms. The C++ stuff is parallel within individual modules, so that's not too bad. The root cause of our problem is that years ago the project was structured as one massive monolithic multi-module project rather than separate projects decoupled via Nexus artifact dependencies.

Comment: I'm leaning towards using the [Partial Build Plugin] (https://github.com/lesfurets/partial-build-plugin) to do the actual module building based on detected Git changes. Instead of global ${revision} versioning we would have to have a global dependencyManagement for each of the 400 modules. Every time one of the modules is built, its version gets updated. So a fairly complex solution, I was wondering if anyone could think of something simpler!

Comment: I haven't tried it but maybe it is worth looking at http://danielflower.github.io/multi-module-maven-release-plugin/index.html

Comment: 400 modules is not that much ...I've had projects with ca. 1000 modules with -T 5 which builds in 6 minutes..but needed some improvements of hardware and infrastructure...and 2000 tests is not much ...so this means those tests are not unit tests etc. one problem...combinations with Ant/Make is the issues...